# Proving a bound for relative error of the power method for determining largest eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume

- $A$ is diagonalizable
- with eigenvalues $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_j| \forall j > 1$ and eigenvectors $\{u^{(j)}\}$, and
- we have an initial $x^{0} \in span(u^{(j)})$ with $x^{(0)} \not \perp u^{(1)}$.

The power method is defined as $x^{k} = A x^{(k-1)} = A^k x^{(0)}$.

Let $\phi$ be a linear functional, and $r_k = \frac{\phi(x^{(k+1)}}{\phi(x^{(k)}}$. We know then that $r_k$ converges to the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$.

I want to show that the relative error $\frac{r_k - \lambda_1}{\lambda_1}$ is equal to:

$$\frac{r_k - \lambda_1}{\lambda_1} = (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k c_k$$

where $c_k$ is some bounded sequence.

How do I do this?

#### My work so far:

In the analysis of the power method we can express $x^{(0)}$ in terms of the eigenvectors $u^{(j)}$:

$x^{(0)} = \sum_j^n a_j u^{(j)}$

where we can omit the $a_j$ (and just rescale $u^{(j)}$, which are orthogonal). From the definition of the power method we have

$x^{(k)} \\
= A^k x^{(0)} \\
= A^k \sum_j^n u^{(j)} \\
= \sum_j^n A^k u^{(j)} \\
= \sum_j^n \lambda_j^k u^{(j)} \\
= \lambda_1^k (u^{(1)} + (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k u^{(2)} + \sum_{j=3}^n (\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^k u^{(j)}) \\
= \lambda_1^k (u^{(1)} + (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k u^{(2)} + \epsilon^{(k)})$

where $\epsilon^{(k)} = \sum_{j=3}^n (\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^k u^{(j)}$

$r_k$ is the ratio of linear functionals, so (writing $x_k$ instead of $x^{(k)}$)

$\displaystyle
\frac{r_k - \lambda_1}{\lambda_1} 
\\ 
= \frac{\frac{\phi(x_{k+1})}{\phi(x_k)} - \lambda_1}{\lambda_1} \\
= \frac{\phi(x_{k+1}) - \lambda_1 \phi(x_k)}{\lambda_1 \phi(x_k)} \\
= \frac{\phi(x_{k+1} - \lambda_1 x_k)}{\phi(\lambda_1 x_k)}$

First let’s analyze the numerator:

$x^{(k+1)} - \lambda_1 x^{(k)} \\
= \lambda_1^{k+1} (u^{(1)} + (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k+1} u^{(2)} + \sum_{j=3}^n (\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^{k+1} u^{(j)}) - \lambda_1^{k+1} (u^{(1)} + (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k u^{(2)} + \sum_{j=3}^n (\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^k u^{(j)}) \\
= \lambda_1^{k+1} (((\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k+1} - (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k) u^{(2)} + \sum_{j=3}^n ((\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^{k+1} - (\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^k ) u^{(j)}) \\
= \lambda_1^{k+1} (((\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k+1} - (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k) u^{(2)} + \sum_{j=3}^n ((\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^{k+1} - (\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1})^k ) u^{(j)})$

or using $\epsilon^{(k)}$,

$= \lambda_1^{k+1} (((\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k+1} - (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k) u^{(2)} + e^{(k+1)} - e^{(k)})$

$= \lambda_1^{k+1} ((\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k}(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} - 1) u^{(2)} + e^{(k+1)} - e^{(k)})$

$\implies \phi(x^{(k+1)} - \lambda_1 x^{(k)}) \\
= \lambda_1^{k+1} \phi((\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k}(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} - 1) u^{(2)} + e^{(k+1)} - e^{(k)}) \\
= \lambda_1^{k+1} ((\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k}(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} - 1) \phi(u^{(2)}) + \phi(e^{(k+1)} - e^{(k)}))$

And the denominator:

$\phi(\lambda_1 x^{(k)}) \\
= \phi(\lambda_1^{k+1} (u^{(1)} + (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k u^{(2)} + \epsilon^{(k)})) \\
= \lambda_1^{k+1} (\phi(u^{(1)}) + (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k \phi(u^{(2)}) + \phi(\epsilon^{(k)})))$

So

$\displaystyle 
\frac{\phi(x_{k+1} - \lambda_1 x_k)}{\phi(\lambda_1 x_k)} \\
= \frac{(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^{k}(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} - 1) \phi(u^{(2)}) + \phi(e^{(k+1)} - e^{(k)})}{\phi(u^{(1)}) + (\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k \phi(u^{(2)}) + \phi(\epsilon^{(k)}))}$

But I can't seem to find a way to derive the desired expression.